# HOw to give path of hibernate xml file in web-inf folder

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using eclispe

in my java class i need to give the path of hibernate cfg.xml like

```
.configure("WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")
```

but this is not working but it works if i copy file to some packagae  like

```
.configure("com/user/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml")
```

How can i give path of web-inf folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration().configure(String resource)` looks for the file in the classpath.

If you have a servletContext, you can try

```
URL configFile = getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/hibernate.xml");
Configuration().configure(configFile)
```